# 'Assign Agents' action in Omni Supervisor isn't showing agents

Tags: omnichannel, omni-supervisor

I'm running into an issue with Omni-Channel supervisor settings. I'm trying to set what agents are to be shown when moving assigning them to queues within Omni Supervisor. I created a public group called 'Omni Agents' and assigned ~6 roles to the group. I assigned the group to the 'Selected Visible Agents' setting. For some reason, no agents are showing up. I've also ensured that my profile, Sys Admin, was assigned in the config (Select the Supervisor profiles that this configuration applies).

The workaround is to select a ton of agents manually, but it's not scalable due to high turnover. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image: Omni Settings]

[image: No Agents]